# Check if Realm Object contains a specific value in array - Swift

Tags: swift, realm

When you have a Realm model that looks something like:

```
class Thing {
  var id: String?
  var kids: List<String>
}
```

And have Thing objects like: `Thing(id: "thingyOne", kids: List<"Momo", "Jojo">)`. You can easily query for objects that have id of "thingyOne" using `Realm().objects(Thing.self).filter("id == 'thingyOne'")`. How do you check which objects have kids named "Jojo" in their kids list?

I'm currently using this method:

```
let things = Realm().objects(Thing.self)
for thing in things {
    if thing.kids.contains("Jojo") {
        // Success
    }
}
```

This makes the app extremely slow because I have thousands of Realm objects. How do you do it the correct way?

Comment: I think this might be what a "subquery" is for.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it could be used in this example? I think it only works if you have another Realm object as a variable inside the original Realm object, in this case, Thing.

Comment: This isn't natively supported, but as @Alexander-ReinstateMonica says a subquery will handle it. This link (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334) will lead you to the issue regarding implementation on Realm github, and there is a comment containing an example subquery to help you (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334#issuecomment-429268995).

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be a huge issue as I have a JSON with thousands of objects. It looks like the only way out of this is to add a new custom string class with just one string property. Now I have to change all of my arrays in the JSON. Kill me pls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering through large array causes freezing - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674146/filtering-through-large-array-causes-freezing-swift)