# Filtering through large array causes freezing - Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to filter through a large database of objects with arrays of strings, in this case, `kids`.

```
class Thing: Object, Decodable {
  @objc dynamic var id: String?
  let kids = List<String>
}
```

Since Realm does not support querying primitive data in arrays (According to Realm, you can't use a predicate & filter to do this yet), I'm using this to filter through them:

```
let things = realm.objects(Thing.self)
for thing in things {
    if thing.kids.contains("Momo") {
        // Success
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
realm.objects(Thing.self).filter(NSPredicate("%@ IN kids", "Momo"))
```

But it does not work. I also tried to use `SUBQUERY` inside the predicate but it also does not work for primitive data types.

Because I have thousands of `Thing` objects, this is very slow and it freezes my app. Is there a way to speed this up or make it not freeze my app at least? I can't make a new custom class for strings because I would have to completely change my JSON, which is where everything is stored.

Comment: Do it in a background queue.

Comment: Use Realm's built-in `filter` method instead of iterating through a `Results` using a loop.

Comment: You've tagged this question is Realm but that's not a Realm object. Also, there is a way to filter for primitives but we need to see your actual Realm objects. Also, thats not how a List is defined in Realm - it cannot be a var and must be defined as a let `let dogs = List<Dog>()`

Comment: Thanks, David. I can't use Realm's `filter` because it does not support lists of primitive data types yet.

Comment: I fixed it so that it is now a Realm object. I've been reading about filtering through primitives and found [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334). Apparently it is not supported yet. Do you know of another way?

Comment: There is not currently another way to store primitives in a List and filter for them. What's the problem with crafting a Kid realm object with a *name* property and storing those Objects within the List? It makes filtering a snap and very fast - even with thousands of objects.

Comment: That's what I thought of doing and wanted to see if that was a good idea or if there is another way. I was trying to avoid this way because I would have to rewrite all of my arrays in the JSON. It looks like this: `"kids": ["kidOne", "kidTwo"]`. Now I have to change them all to be like `"kids": [{"name": "kidOne"}, {"name": "kidTwo"}]`. Thanks though! In your opinion, would it be better to rewrite the JSON like this or use Felix Marianayagam's solution until Realm supports querying primitives?

Comment: No. That is not a working solution for Realm; see my comments. In fact, if you're iterating over thousands of objects to find one object, you're probably doing it wrong. There are usually better ways to structure data or query for what you need. I don't know if it matters but what happens with your existing code if you have two 'Steve' kids in the list? or 10?  Crafting it in the way I suggest, your KidClass will have unique id's to differentiate one Steve from another. I can provide an answer if needed. Be sure to respond in comments with @Jay so I will be notified of the response.